# Saving image into core data and fetching it into tableview cell

Tags: swift, core-data, uiimage, nsentitydescription

I did a set up of CoreData with entity "users" and attribute "username" (when I type something in uitextfield it saves into core data and I got readings from core data into tableview cell). That is working like a charm. But I also want to display chosen picture from imagepickercontroller  and that is also working fine when I choose picture but when I click save I think I got it saved. I don't know if it is saved because I eliminated all error so I got no errors, but it won't read that picture into tableview cell. I put new attribute "image" with type binary data into core data file but code does not work.

This is code for saving into core data

```
let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Users", inManagedObjectContext: context)

newUser.setValue(nameField.text, forKey: "username")

let picture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoImageView.image!, 1); 
newUser.setValue(picture, forKey: "image")
```

And this is code where tableview reads data from core data

```
cell.imageView!.image = person.valueForKey("image") as? UIImage
```

I also tried with

```
[UIImage, imageWithData:self.myEvent.picture];
```

but Swift 2.0 don't have that syntax imageWithData

Answer (score 0):

`person.valueForKey("image") as? UIImage` won't work.

Use `UIImage(data:)` to convert the retrieved NSData to UIImage.

Comment: let picture object is in first vc , tableview is in second, so how in second vc get that let picture object?

Comment: tried with this in second vc but it does not work let image : UIImage = UIImage(data: person.valueForKey("image") as? UIImage)

Comment: It should not be `as? UIImage`, you saved it as `NSData` with the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. As far as passing data to another view controller, you could use `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: this code is for retrieving data from core data cell.textLabel!.text = person.valueForKey("username") as? String,  how can i use the same principle for uiimage?

Comment: You can't because you did not save your data as UIImage. You saved it as NSData with jpeg representation. Retrieve it as NSData and convert to UIImage using UIImage(data:)

Answer (score 0):

for retrieving image from core data i used this and it is finally working.

```
let image = person.valueForKey("image") as? NSData
    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(data: image!)
```